# The orientation of a closed discrete curve embedded in a triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, computational-geometry

The two triangles $xyz$ and $x^{\prime}y^{\prime}z^{\prime}$, shown below, have opposite orientations. A closed curve $abcd$ is embedded in the first triangle ($abcd$). The vertices of the corresponding closed discrete curve $a^{\prime}b^{\prime}c^{\prime}d^{\prime}$ are  computed by the method of barycentric coordinates. As shown below $a^{\prime}b^{\prime}c^{\prime}d^{\prime}$ will have opposite orientation as $abcd$.

I'd like to know:

1. why the difference in orientation of the embedding triangles leads to a difference in the orientations of the embedded discrete curves.
2. if reversing the orientation of the triangle $xyz$ to match that of $x^{\prime}y^{\prime}z^{\prime}$ is sufficient to is sufficient to ensure that $abcd$ and $a^{\prime}b^{\prime}c^{\prime}d^{\prime}$ have the same orientations.

[image: two triangles with opposite orientations]